# Is it possible to refresh strips in the VSE

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

I have been using an external editor to cut between image sequences created with Blender, but decided to move to the VSE for efficiency.

With the externa editor (Kdenlive), when I made changes to an image sequences, it automatically updated it, or, failing that, there was an update command.

However, with the VSE, the only way I could find to update a strip was to delete it, add it again an recrop it.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the strip and press Alt+R to reload, or Shift+Alt+R to reload and adjust length.