# Is there a way to update a scene that's been added as a video strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

You can add another scene as a strip in the video sequencer, but it does not update when the original scene is changed. The typical advice is to delete and re-add the strip when the scene is updated. This requirement doesn't make sense to me because there's no additional copy of the scene anywhere, so I'm not even sure how Blender is retaining the old data.

I've tried various "reload" options like Alt-R (reload strips) with no effect. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What specifically is not updated in your scene strip? If it is a length could be related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88298/2214 or Refresh All https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149200/2214

Comment: @vklidu I think it's actually caching a proxy of the scene. If I make the scene strip long enough I can see changes update if I move far enough away on the timeline. But the proxy control that work on movie/image strips don't work on Scenes.

Comment: So your issue is that changes in 3D viewport are not reflected in VSE, right? Because what I tried right now Alt+R or Refresh all works for scene strip for me. So probably if you can open a new blend, setup vse and share with us if the issue persists. https://blend-exchange.com/ Thanks

Comment: Ok, I did not realize Alt+R operated on the selected strip. I thought it was a global operation, so I didn't have my strip selected when I tried it. Ctrl+E/Refresh All does work like I expected Alt+R to, I just didn't find it.

Comment: Consider to delete your Q, otherwise system will poke your Q in periods ... and since you solve it there is nothing to answer :) Thank you keep this site organised.